# TexLive 2020 install failure on Windows 10 machine

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I recently tried to install the latest version of TexLive2020 on my Windows 10 computer from DVD.  However, the installation was interrupted for some reason and failed.  I have deleted the main Texlive folder and try to reinstall but that fails because, I think, residual files from the initial install remain.  What is the recommended method to clear out a failed install on Windows?
Thank you.

Comment: Try a minimal install and install after that only the packages you need by using tlmgr ...

Comment: If there was an old non-empty texmf-local then you may have run into a bug in the DVD installer, which was fixed later on. If that is the case, follow the directions in http://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html onder 'Fixing permission problems'.